# Apply google map night mode into project React?

Tags: google-maps, react-native

[React Navite]
How I can apply [Google Map Night Mode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/styling) into project React?

Comment: Try to check this [tutorial](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-yandexmapkit) that shows react native maps that you can apply night mode. It is stated here that a night mode has a boolean value indicating whether the map should be rendered in a night mode. Check the example [here](https://github.com/doomsower/react-native-yandexmapkit/tree/master/example).

Comment: Thanks @KENdi, but plugin [react-native-yandex-map-kit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-yandexmapkit)  don't google map and it don't support the maker.